# What am I missing in this code: "Else without if error"?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I am trying to run this code which first declares `wsD` and then `WsS` depending on a cell in the "Data" tab. I keep getting an

> else without if error.

```
Set wsD = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

    If wsD.Range("C4") = "AL" Then Set wsS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AL_Sim")
    ElseIf wsD.Range("C4") = "COLL" Then Set wsS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("COLL_Sim")
    ElseIf wsD.Range("C4") = "COMP" Then Set wsS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("COMP_Sim")
    ElseIf wsD.Range("C4") = "GL" Then Set wsS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("GL_Sim")
    ElseIf wsD.Range("C4") = "EPL" Then Set wsS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("EPL_Sim")
    ElseIf wsD.Range("C4") = "LAW" Then Set wsS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LAW_Sim")
    ElseIf wsD.Range("C4") = "POL" Then Set wsS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("POL_Sim")

    End If
Next
```

Comment: Is this a for loop? Can’t see the for in your code. Paste all ur code pls

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the actions on new lines:

```
If wsD.Range("C4") = "AL" Then
    Set wsS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AL_Sim")
ElseIf wsD.Range("C4") = "COLL" Then
    Set wsS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("COLL_Sim")
ElseIf wsD.Range("C4") = "COMP" Then
    Set wsS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("COMP_Sim")
ElseIf wsD.Range("C4") = "GL" Then
    Set wsS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("GL_Sim")
ElseIf wsD.Range("C4") = "EPL" Then
    Set wsS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("EPL_Sim")
ElseIf wsD.Range("C4") = "LAW" Then
    Set wsS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LAW_Sim")
ElseIf wsD.Range("C4") = "POL" Then
    Set wsS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("POL_Sim")
End If
```

`Select Case` would be better here:

```
Select Case wsD.Range("C4")
    Case Is = "AL"
        Set wsS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AL_Sim")
    Case Is = "COLL"
        Set wsS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("COLL_Sim")
    Case Is = "COMP"
        Set wsS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("COMP_Sim")
    Case Is = "GL"
        Set wsS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("GL_Sim")
    Case Is = "EPL"
        Set wsS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("EPL_Sim")
    Case Is = "LAW"
        Set wsS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LAW_Sim")
    Case Is = "POL"
        Set wsS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("POL_Sim")
End Select
```

Comment: You could simplify the `Select Case` too, based on the concatenation of the Range value and "_Sim".

Comment: Agreed, there are other modifications too, like using `With` to get rid of all the `ThisWorkbook` references, but I don't know what the rest of the code looks like, so I want to provide a solution with the least assumptions being made.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think a new line would make a difference.

Comment: You're welcome, if this solution resolved the issue you were experiencing please mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 10):

The `If` statement has two legal syntaxes.

Inline:

```
If {bool-expression} Then {statement}
```

And block:

```
If {bool-expression} Then
    {statements}
End If
```

So if there's a statement on the same line following the `Then` keyword, VBA parses the `If` statement as the inline syntax.

Thus, since the statement is complete, the next statement beginning with `ElseIf` makes no sense to the compiler: there's an "else without if".

Answer (score 7):

There is a little known fact *(or how I like to refer it, Microsoft's little practical joke..)* in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba), that the **`If..Then..End If`** condition has actually two established forms:

1. Single-line syntax
2. Multi-line syntax

You basically mixed up multi-line and single-line syntax into one *mush*, as per [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/if-then-else-statement):

> What follows the `Then` keyword is examined to determine whether a
>   statement is a single-line `If`. **If anything other than a comment
>   appears after `Then` on the same line, the statement is treated as a
>   single-line If statement.** If `Then` is absent, it must be the start of a
>   multiple-line `If...Then...Else`.

Example of a single-line statement:

```
If <condition> Then <expression>
```

and multi-line *(what you attempted to do)*:

```
If <condition> Then
  <expression>
ElseIf <condition> Then 'optional, note comment isn't evaluated as single-line expression
  <expression>
End If
```

So to sum it up, your code threw an error, because the `ElseIf` got evaluated as an *`<expression>`* after the `If..Then` statement, instead to evaluating to a conditional like you intended it to.

---

> The unwritten rule goes, **always write in multi-line syntax**.
>   Not only you will steer clear of unnecessary errors (like you just
>   encountered), but it is also inarguably easier to read and the
>   standard amongst coders.