# Trigger macro automatically on cell value change |Excel|VBA|

Tags: excel, vba

Sheet 1  as ENTER VALUE

[image]

Sheet 2 as MY VALUE and DATA

[image]

Sheet value is referenced from Sheet1 Value using `=Sheet1!E4`

I want to avoid onclick Button event => as soon as value in sheet 1 changes to 10 then My value in sheet 2 changes to 10 => then taking the value which is changed in sheet 2 the macros should automatically detect the value change as occured then print of Data should happen that many times in column I

Module 1 *my macros*  :

```
Sub mac()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rDest As Range
Dim lCount As Long
Dim sValue As String

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set rDest = ws.Range("I2")

With ws.Range(rDest, ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, rDest.Column).End(xlUp))
    If .Row >= rDest.Row Then .ClearContents
End With

lCount = Val(ws.Range("E4").Value)
sValue = ws.Range("E8").Value

If lCount > 0 Then rDest.Resize(lCount) = sValue

End Sub
```

Sheet 2 : Code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Application.Intersect(Range("E4"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
Call mac
End Sub
```

output : should be like this below 
[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQGrB.png)): https://i.stack.imgur.com/voz7g.png

Comment: You've added quite a lot of detail, but not quite clear what you think is not working...?

Comment: You probably want to use that `Worksheet_Change` event in `Sheet1` instead? And set your worksheet by name in your function `Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA trigger macro on cell value change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500608/vba-trigger-macro-on-cell-value-change)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things

- Your `Worksheet_Change` procedure should be in `Sheet1` code instead of `Sheet2` - least from the way you phrased your question.
- Also be explicit with your `Worksheet` declarations *(eg. `Sheets("Sheet1")`)*, instead of using things like `ActiveSheet`
- In your `Intersect`, notation of `Range(Target.Address)` is completely redundant, as `Target` already is a `Range` object.

---

Your code in `Sheet1` should be:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E4"), Target) Is Nothing Then
       Call mac
    End If
End Sub
```

And In `Module`

```
Private Sub mac()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rDest As Range
Dim lCount As Long
Dim sValue As String

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") ' note the explicit declaration
Set rDest = ws.Range("I2")

With ws.Range(rDest, ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, rDest.Column).End(xlUp))
    If .Row >= rDest.Row Then .ClearContents
End With

lCount = Val(ws.Range("E4").Value)
sValue = ws.Range("E8").Value

If lCount > 0 Then rDest.Resize(lCount) = sValue

End Sub
```

> And as a personal note, I would beware of using "single-line `If` syntax" in my opinion it is a bad programming practice and leads to unexpected mistakes and worse code readability.
>
> > As a good example as to why, check [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55812422/5512705)

Comment: Then you have something wrong with your macro procedure, I can't read your mind, but my answer is programatically correct

Comment: Thanks Bro Working !!! Little Bit changes i made Sheet 1 Code it should be F5 not sheet 2 Value 'E4' => We need to pass value of sheet 1

Comment: Well glad it helped.

Comment: is it possible to take two values and print parallel like this => https://paste.pics/3eb581ed87184d251d910328537f2973          => it would be really helpful for me

Comment: create a separate question for that

Comment: => i have created a Separate Question please have a look at it => run macros dynamically on value change |VBA|Excel|   =>  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56311747/run-macros-dynamically-on-value-change-vbaexcel