# run macros dynamically on value change |VBA|Excel|

Tags: excel, vba

I have Sheet 1 and Sheet

Sheet 1 => https://paste.pics/6d48d50d54592eb1bdcb31e727b44958

Sheet 2 => https://paste.pics/80f4230bf6819a80ed36e1b6415ece08

Value of Sheet 1 => F5 => '50'  => is referenced in Sheet 2  => E4 => '50'

When i enter Value in Sheet 1 in place of F5 => Value gets Change in Sheet 2 => E4 => Automatically

Now the issue is I want to print the DATA 1 and DATA 2 of Sheet 2 => That many times => how much value which is shown in place of Sheet 2 => E4 [Position] => in place of COLUMN => 'I' and 'J'

Like this Below Output :https://paste.pics/494c856d2908a83ca031ee20bb706a09

My code which partially print only one Column output but need to PRINT 'RAM' and 'RAJ' => COLUMN => 'I' and 'J'

**Module :**
Sub mac()

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rDest As Range
Dim lCount As Long
Dim sValue As String

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Set rDest = ws.Range("I2")

With ws.Range(rDest, ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, rDest.Column).End(xlUp))
    If .Row >= rDest.Row Then .ClearContents
End With

lCount = Val(ws.Range("E4").Value)
sValue = ws.Range("E8").Value

If lCount > 0 Then rDest.Resize(lCount) = sValue

End Sub
```

**Sheet  1 code :**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F5"), Target) Is Nothing Then
       Call mac
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Print means what. Print by printer or just fill the cells.

Answer (score 0):

If print means just filling the cells, then you can use following sub. Modify the code to adjust it with `Worksheet_Change` event

```
Sub FillNames()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i, destLen As Long

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet2")
destLen = ws.Range("E4")

    For i = 1 To destLen
        ws.Cells(i + 1, "I") = ws.Range("E8")
        ws.Cells(i + 1, "J") = ws.Range("E12")
    Next

Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: => i have one issue => when value in E4 is 50 => it prints in column I and J => the DATA 1 and DATA 2  50 times and if value is more then 50 this condition also works as it appends and it is true it prints But what if i give value less then 50 it is not updating the column I and J and Printing the DATA 1 and DATA 2 as mentioned value is less than 50 => there as to be some clear data function

Comment: => it as some flaws please have a look at this => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56313109/how-do-i-clear-column-and-fill-data-again-if-value-is-less-than-old-value-excel

Comment: @Harun24Hr Note that `Dim i, destLen As Long` only declares `destLen` as `Long` but `i` as `Variant`. In VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable otherwise it is `Variant` by default: `Dim i As Long, destLen As Long`