# How do i clear column and fill data again if value is less than old value |excel|VBA|

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Excel

**Sheet 1**

[image: Sheet1]

**Sheet 2**

[image: Sheet2]

Value of Sheet 1 => F5 => '50'  => is referenced in Sheet 2  => E4 => '50'

When i enter Value in Sheet 1 in place of F5 => Value gets Change in Sheet 2 => E4 => Automatically

using below code the DATA is Printed that many times 
My code

**module : mac**

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rDest As Range
Dim lCount As Long
Dim sValue As String

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Set rDest = ws.Range("I2")

With ws.Range(rDest, ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, rDest.Column).End(xlUp))
    If .Row >= rDest.Row Then .ClearContents
End With

lCount = Val(ws.Range("E4").Value)
sValue = ws.Range("E8").Value

If lCount > 0 Then rDest.Resize(lCount) = sValue

End Sub
```

**Sheet 1 Code:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F5"), Target) Is Nothing Then
       Call mac
    End If
End Sub
```

**This is the Output**

Like this Below Output :

https://paste.pics/494c856d2908a83ca031ee20bb706a09

My Above code Works Perfectly according to above mentioned output
But as Some Flaws in it

**Assume**

**Condition 1:**

if the value entered is '50'  => then data in the Column "I" and "J" gets printed 50 times =>  right [Perfect]

**Condition 2:**

if the value entered is '60'  => then data in the Coulmn "I" and "J" gets appends
with the previous data which it as "50"  => 50 + 10 => 60  => this is right [perfect]

**Condition 3:**

Assume the Column "I:J" already as DATA => upto the Range '60' 
if the entered value is less then '60'  like '30' then updation should happen only 30 times in Column "I:J" the Data should be Printed But Nothing is happening
appending happens but clearing data does not happen if range is lesser then old value

**There as to be some mechanism like**

if Count is 50 => print => I,J

if Count is more then 50 => append I,J

if Count is less then 50 => clear column I,J and then => fill the Column I ,J

**How do i achieve this mechanism?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell your code works... is just a matter of expanding the range if 
 I understood right what you are asking. See comments for the only 2 changes done to your code:

```vb
Sub mac()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rDest As Range
Dim lCount As Long
Dim sValue As String

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Set rDest = ws.Range("I2")

With ws.Range(rDest, ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, rDest.Column + 1).End(xlUp)) 'Add another column to your selection here
    If .Row >= rDest.Row Then .ClearContents
End With

lCount = Val(ws.Range("E4").Value)
sValue = ws.Range("E8").Value

If lCount > 0 Then rDest.Resize(lCount, 2) = sValue 'Resize to 2 columns instead of the default 1.

End Sub
```

PS: please let me know if I misunderstood your query.